# Is it Optimal to balance RAM across banks

Tags: memory, performance, dual-channel

It's well known that using matched pairs of RAM in a single bank with Dual Channel Architecture is optimal, both so that the two sticks have similar timings, equal capacity, etc.

But what about between two banks?

I have a P8Z68-V (Gen3) motherboard, with 2x4GB in one channel. This leaves the second channel free. For optimal performance, should this be filled with *another* 2x4GB, or does it not matter, so long as the channel itself is balanced? i.e. could I stick in 2x8GB (to give a total of 24GB of RAM) and not suffer any performance issues/get the best performance?

Comment: So long as each is a matched pair, i.e. the same number of GB, then the pairs can all be different, so long as they are matched for speed etc. Anecdotally, my spare machine has 26GB, made up of 2x2, 2x4 & 2x8 [+ 2 spare slots] with no ill-effects.

Answer (score 2):

You have it backwards. The most important thing is having the same amount of RAM on each channel.